# Paid Android app is unavailable for users

Tags: android

I have a lite version of my Android app, which users can download for free. I have tons of people emailing me saying that they can download the free version just fine, but when they go to download the paid version it's saying the app in unavailable for their device. The app is built the exact same way and the users have no problem downloading other paid apps. Any idea why it won't allow some users to download the paid version? 
Thanks

Here are the manifest files:

```
<!-- FULL -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.paidapp.full"
      android:versionCode="4" android:versionName="1.0">


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">

        <activity android:name="com.paidapp.MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <supports-screens
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:normalScreens="true"
          android:smallScreens="true"
          android:anyDensity="false" 
     />

     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" android:required="true"/>
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="true"/>
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true"/>
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="true"/>
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="true"/>
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true"/>

</manifest> 


<!-- FREE -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.freeapp.free"
      android:versionCode="4" android:versionName="1.0">


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon_lite" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">

        <activity android:name="com.freeapp.MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>




    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <supports-screens
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:normalScreens="true"
          android:smallScreens="true"
          android:anyDensity="false" 
     />

     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" android:required="true"/>
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="true"/>
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true"/>
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="true"/>
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="true"/>
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post manifest file first, for both build versions.

Comment: Just posted it, hope that helps